# Disable macOS screen capture snapshot sound?

Tags: macos, keyboard, audio

I'm not using Grab, but the [screenshot shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11229) <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>

A loud snapshot sound plays whenever I screengrab.

How can I turn off this sound, and is there any way other than disabling all system sound effects? Perhaps with a Terminal command?

I'm looking specifically for 10.8+, if it matters.

[image: Sound]

Comment: i don't know if you know this, but a quick tap on the mute button before taking the picture will do the trick

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In short:** replace the `Grab.aif` file with a blank audio file.

---

1. Go to `/System/Library/Components`
2. Right click on `CoreAudio.Component` & select `Show Package Content`

[image: Apple Component Library]

3. Go under `Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system`

[image]

4. Make a back up of `Grab.aif` (duplicate it)
5. Replace `Grab.aif` by an empty audio file

### Links/Resources

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=797999

Comment: How to generate an empty aif audio file?

Comment: I can't put anything into the folder `Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system`, even when using `sudo`

Comment: does this still work under SIP?

Comment: @theonlygusti `touch ~/Desktop/Grab.aif` will generate an empty aif file on your desktop

Answer (score 19):

The easy version: Disable all the sound effects

1. Click on the Apple logo in the top-left corner of your screen and select “System Preferences…”

[image]

2. Click on the option that says “Sound”

[image]

3. Click on “Sound Effects”

[image]

Comment: This was way easier and worked great.

Comment: funny enough the question explicitly stated "and is there any way other than disabling all system sound effects" :)

Comment: this doesn't work in OS Venutra. As in.. it works but will disable all your notifications sounds too such as slack notifications. not sure why apple makes simple things notoriously difficult.