# Built-in way to mute audio on Catalina?

Tags: applescript, catalina, shortcut

Question:

I need a short cut to mute my mac without using the touchbar, so no sound of taking a snapshot of my screen(<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>-click). I don't like third-party software I want a built-in way to do it.

---

My trying:

[image]

Oh, I forgot to save the changed. I've solved it with the following code:

```
if output muted of (get volume settings) is false then
    set volume with output muted
else
    set volume without output muted
end if
```

I found that the shortcut <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> didn't trigger the Automator, but <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> works for me.

Comment: Why can't you use the touch bar? That's what it's there for.

Comment: So you want a multi-button short cut to do what a single button press was designed for?  How about clicking on the volume icon in the menu bar and lowering the volume to zero?

Comment: How about one of these methods?  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100946/disable-snapshot-sound-during-screen-capture-keyboard-shortcut-on-10-8

Comment: What is the actual question here? From reading your post I see a solution but no actual question?! If you found a way to solve the problem, can you please rollback the edits and post the solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 2):

First, you're going to need an AppleScript that can mute the system audio.

```
set volume 0
```

Now you need a way to execute this script from anywhere. We'll use macOS services, and Automator makes this super easy for us.

1. Open Automator
2. Make a New Document of type "Quick Action" *(or "Service" in older macOS)*
3. Drag a new **Run Applescript** action into the workflow. You can find it in the Utilities category, or just search for it in the search bar.
4. Copy the AppleScript shown above into the script box.
5. Press <kbd>▶</kbd> to try it out.
6. Save the workflow as `Mute System Audio`. The moment you save it, it will become accessible from the Services menu under the application menu.

Cool, now let's hook it up as a global keyboard shortcut.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go into Keyboard Preferences
3. Go to the Shortcuts tab
4. Go into the Services category
5. Scroll down to the bottom. Underneath General you should see Swap Front Windows.
6. Select the "Mute System Audio" row, then click Add Shortcut.
7. Enter the shortcut you want to use. I recommend <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Reply to your first comment: I don't want to move my sight to see where the button is, and this is inconvenient for me...

Comment: I did 5., it didn't mute the audio?

Comment: If I close the Automator the shortcut doesn't work, how to fix this?

Comment: @Niing Did you make sure to create it as *Quick Action*? If you follow the steps *exactly* it should work.